# forcing all http requests to follow system proxy configuration

Tags: ruby, web-services, proxy-server

I am working with a ruby application that uses some loosely coupled modules that interface with a web service. These modules use net::http module of ruby for network communication. But the original code has no means to specify proxy configurations. And of course ruby's net::http does not respect system proxy configuration.

I would like to know if there is a way to channelize all the http requests through the proxy server specified by path variable 'http_proxy' without changing these modules. (These modules are separately maintained and making hard changes would make things difficult while updating them in future)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly this problem and it seems that the ruby-proxifier is a gem that ought to be able to help with this:
https://github.com/samuelkadolph/ruby-proxifier